# Get an NFT's last sale price

Tags: ether, etherscan, nft, erc-721, opensea

How can I fetch the last sale price for an NFT? Basically need to do this for all the NFTs in a collection.

Finding out the real cost price of all owners in the collection at this moment. What's the easiest and quickest way to do this?

Opensea's api isnt helpful. Would be great if someone pointed out the correct direction to look into. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sales are not part of ERC721, you may tap on OpenSea's transaction events and read auction bids along with transfers.

Look at [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7f268357a8c2552623316e2562d90e642bb538e5#events), OpenSea's contract events.